# Excel sheet Runtime error 13: Type mismatch.

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Reset_Bet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Sheets("Bet Angel").Select
            Range( _
                "O6,O9,O11,O13,O15,O17,O19,O21,O23,O25,O27,O29,O31,O33,O35,O37,O39,O41,O43,O45,O47,O49,O51,O53,O55,O57,O59,O61,O63,O65,O67").Activate
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("H2").Select
            Sheets("Dashboard").Select
            Range("D1").Select
            Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A26") = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub TIME_CHECK()
    If Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A26") >= Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("L19") Then Call Reset_Bet
    If Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A27") >= Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("L20") Then Range("A27") = 0
End Sub

Sub TIMEODD()
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("a25") = 1
    **Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A26") = Range("A26") + 1**
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A27") = Range("A27") + 1
    Call TIME_CHECK
End Sub

Sub TIMEEVEN()
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("a25") = 0
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A26") = Range("A26") + 1
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A27") = Range("A27") + 1
    Call TIME_CHECK
End Sub

Public Sub arrRecorder()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Recorder")
    ' Excel 2003 only has 65536 rows
    Dim maxRows As Long
    maxRows = 65536 ' This value must not be more than the number of rows allowed in Excel

    ' Clear data after selecting a new market, if that option is ticked
    If (ws.Range("A4").Value <> ws.Range("A7").Value) And ws.Range("A7").Value <> "" And ws.Range("D1").Value = True Then
        Module1.Clear_Data
    End If

    ' Check whether logging is enabled
    If (ws.Range("D2") = True) Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' Find the last used row
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastUsedRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        'Find the last column
        Dim lastUsedColumn As Long
        lastUsedColumn = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

        ' Clear the last used row, so that there is not an error if we try to move data down beyond the last row
        ' Deleting a row is not super fast, so we only do it if necessary.
        ' So we do not bother to delete the last used row unless it is near the end of the spreadsheet
        ' This also ensures that we never accidentally delete our top row containing formulae.
        If lastUsedRow >= maxRows Then
            ' Now delete cells in the last used row (across as far as the lastUsedColumn)
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastUsedRow, 1), ws.Cells(lastUsedRow, lastUsedColumn)).Delete
        End If

        ' Now move all the data down by one row, by inserting a row
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 1), ws.Cells(5, lastUsedColumn)).Insert shift:=xlDown

        Dim arr As Variant
        'arr = ws.Range("A3:AF3")
        arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 1), ws.Cells(4, lastUsedColumn))

        Dim destination As Range
        Set destination = ws.Range("A7")
        destination.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
        ' Other ways to copy the data:
        'ws.Range("A7:AF5").Value = arr
        'ws.Range("A7:AF5").Value = ws.Range("A4:AF3").Value
        'ws.Range("A7:AF5").Copy destination: ws.Range ("A4:AF3")

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If


End Sub

Sub Clear_Data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Recorder")
    'ws.Range("A5:AF65536").delete shift:=xlUp
    Dim lastDataColumn As Long
    lastDataColumn = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(7, 1), ws.Cells(65536, lastDataColumn)).Clear
End Sub
Sub NotActive()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Recorder")
    ' Just log it once that the market is not active (i.e. Suspended or Closed)
    ' There is no need to log it more than once, because prices don't change when the market is not active
    If ws.Range("D4") <> ws.Range("D7") Then
        Call arrRecorder
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to record betting odds and in recorder sheet and trying to place bets automatically in dashboard sheet. Recorder works fine but its not displaying odds on the other sheets whereever i linked them. Secondly when i start the sheet its give me an error of Runtime error '13': TypeMismatch. And when i click on debug it takes me to this line "Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A26") = Range("A26") + 1"

Please help me.

Comment: Please check that the cell `A26` on the sheet `Dashboards` has a `number` with the **correct format**. it may be the case you have a string or text in there instead of a number. If that is the case the mismatch will trigger

Comment: You should qualify every call to Range() with a worksheet object, otherwise they default to the active sheet.

Comment: There is a number in that cell.

Comment: how do i do that ? i just copy this code from some where i have a very little knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Sub TIMEODD()
    With Worksheets("Dashboard")
        .Range("a25") = 1
        .Range("A26") = .Range("A26") + 1
        .Range("A27") = .Range("A27") + 1
    End With
    Call TIME_CHECK
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the mistype error but my first problem is still there. Recorder works fine but its not displaying odds on the other sheets wherever i linked them. its recording all the odds but not showing that on other sheets.